# Запуск исполняемого файла и коды возврата в php

Tags: php, c++, linux

Что означают коды возврата? Ну, например, запускаю я исполняемый файл в php, мне возвращает 139.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
system('/home/re1aps/insert', $retval);
echo '
</pre>'
<hr />Kod vozvrata: ' . $retval;'
?>
```

Собственно бинарник такой:

```
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MYSQL *conn;

  int len, size;
  char data[1000*1024];
  char chunk[2*1000*1024+1];
  char query[1024*5000];

  FILE *fp;

  conn = mysql_init(NULL);
  mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "", "bd", 0, NULL, 0);

  fp = fopen("test.jpg", "rb");
  size = fread(data, 1, 1024*1000, fp);

  mysql_real_escape_string(conn, chunk, data, size);

  int val1= 1 ,val2= 2;

  char stat[] = "INSERT INTO img(id, pic, name) VALUES(\'%d\', \'%s\', \'%d\')";
  len = snprintf(query, sizeof(stat)+sizeof(chunk) , stat, val1, chunk, val2);

  mysql_real_query(conn, query, len);

  fclose(fp);
  mysql_close(conn);
}
```

В итоге, ничего не запускается и не добавляется. Да я знаю, все это можно сделать и на чистом php, но это только часть программы, основная программа сложный расчет - на php такое либо глупо делать, либо не реально, скорее первое. Да из консоли если запускать все работает.

P.s. Но если я пишу элементарный код - то все окей. К примеру, вывожу в консоль "hello world". То же самое выводится и в браузере, но стоит чуть усложнить и в браузере сыпятся ошибки. Конкретно какие были: 1, 127, 139 вроде это основные, по-поводу них ничего не нашел, что они вообще означают?

Comment: Не факт, что при запуске из-под сервера система выделит столько памяти. Вообще объявлять массивы такого размера - в корне неправильно. Попробуйте выделять память динамически и смотреть на коды ошибок, может тут что всплывёт.

Comment: Да этот код ерунда, скажем тестовый файл для базы. Хм...тогда получается что бинарник в котором рассчитываются данные о картинке вообще не запустится? Конкретно если запускать тот бинарник, то в браузер возвращается код "1", ни как не могу понять, что это значит.

Comment: "тогда получается что бинарник в котором рассчитываются данные о картинке вообще не запустится?" - понятия не имею. Если постараться, то и "Hello, world" не запустится, а программа для рассчёта маршрута шаттла будет работать. Попробуйте выделять память динамически, или просто уменьшить аппетиты (нафига там столько? потребности ведь можно определить) - видно будет.

Comment: Хоть удаляй этот код:) В общем рассуждать можно о многих вещах, намек на то, что если запустится этот код, то и другой тоже запустится. А вообще я бы не проч почитать про то как запускать "программа для рассчёта маршрута шаттла", может есть какой нибудь универсальный вариант для запуска любых приложений? Да и мне вот еще что кажется - возможно у меня неправильно веб-сервер настроен? было бы не плохо, если кто-нибудь отписался бы кто реально запускал бинарники из под php.

Comment: Кстати, о HW. Программа

    #include <stdio.h>
    main() {
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
    }

содержит типичную ошибку - она **не возвращает код возврата**. Правильнее так:

    #include <stdio.h>
    main() {
        return printf("Hello, World!\n"), 
               fflush(stdout); // fflush returns 0 on success
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, конечно, но у меня при [чисто для теста!!! :)]

```
chmod 777 /var/www/
код на си:
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   system("echo yap > test.txt");
   return 0;
}
и код на php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$result = 0;
$result = system("/var/www/a.out");
echo "out: ".$result."</br>";
?>
Выдает:
out: 0
и в каталоге /var/www/ создается файл test.txt с текстом yap
```

Смотри, может с правами доступа у тебя проблема. Тем более запуск из терминала - это один пользователь (re1aps) и у него в `/home/re1aps` свои права и своя группа.

Answer (score 2):

Код возврата это число от 0 до 255 (очевидно ему же сответствует -1), которое передается в функцию (системный вызов) exit, или возвращается оператором return из main.

В *nix некоторые коды возврата описаны в /usr/include/sysexits.h

Традиционно код возврата, отличный от нуля, говорит об ошибке. Если Вы явно не возврашаете код (из программы на С/C++), то он **случаен**.

Завершите свою программу

```
    return 0; // OK
или
    exit(0); // OK
```

Comment: @avp, в данном случае мы не знаем, что вернула функция system(), поэтому как интерпретировать значение $retval тоже не знаем :-) Но я почти уверен, что бинарник с такой кучей статических данных может и не запуститься под сервером вообще.

Comment: system совершенно очевидно возвращает  код завершения, который возвращает выполняемая ею команда (Ваша программа) или -1 (он же 255), если не может запустить команду (файл не найден, прав нет и т.п.).

При завершении команды по сигналу могут быть некоторые ньюансы (надо конкретно ПХП смотреть), но здесь об этом речь не идет.

Comment: добавил ретурн и в Hello world и скрипт описанный в топике - разницы нет все тоже самое. Код 139. Что за код такой я хз...сейчас одна идея пришла попробую реализовать.

Comment: @Re1aps, в linux bash выдает такой код (команда echo $? по завершению программы), если прервать ее выполнение сигналом 11 (команда kill -11 PID из другого окошка). 

Это сигнал SIGSEGV, который обычно возникает при ошибке обращения к памяти (попросту программа пишет или читает по недоступным адресам).

Почему это происходит с php->system->helloworld ???  Не знаю.

Comment: @avp, не надо забывать, что system() в PHP не возвращает код завершения программы :) Для начала я бы убедился, что system() !== FALSE, и если тут всё OK, то нужно переписать сишный код нормально. То есть вставить проверки ошибок при вызове mysql_*(), fopen(), при выделении памяти... И только уже по результатам этого думать дальше.

Answer (score 0):

[Коды ошибок windows](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/win_errors.html).
Код ошибки: `139 (0x008B)`.
Попытка отобразить диск на папку, находящуюся на отображенном диске.

Comment: что за чушь? при чем здесь windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

main()
{    
    system("/home/re1aps/insert");
    std::cout << "hello angry php:(" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Попытался запустить такой бинарник, ну собственно текст печатает, а систем не выполняет. В консоле опять же все ок.